# Invalid pointer (malloc)

Tags: c, sigabrt

I'm getting this error when I try to run successfully compiled program:

```
*** Error in `./sharpen': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000e7c030 ***
Neúspěšně ukončen (SIGABRT) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])
```

I'm looking hard into the code and can't seem to find anything that would cause this error happen.

This is issued piece of code:

```
unsigned char* apply_filter(unsigned char *original, header_t header) {
    unsigned char *pixel_array = malloc(header.width * header.height * 3);

    if(pixel_array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected memory error! Out of memory!\n");
        free(pixel_array);
        exit(3);                // Memory was exceeded or something else happened to memory
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < header.height; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < header.width; ++j) {
            if(i == 0 || i == header.height - 1 || j == 0 || j == header.width - 1) {
                pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j)]     = original[3 * (header.width * i + j)];
                pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 1] = original[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 1];
                pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 2] = original[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 2];
            } else {
                // middle pixel
                short pixel_red   = 5 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j)];
                short pixel_green = 5 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 1];
                short pixel_blue  = 5 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 2];

                // backward and forward rows
                pixel_red   += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * (i - 1) + j)];
                pixel_green += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * (i - 1) + j) + 1];
                pixel_blue  += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * (i - 1) + j) + 2];

                pixel_red   += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * (i + 1) + j)];
                pixel_green += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * (i + 1) + j) + 1];
                pixel_blue  += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * (i + 1) + j) + 2];

                // backward and forward cols
                pixel_red   += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j - 1)];
                pixel_green += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j - 1) + 1];
                pixel_blue  += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j - 1) + 2];

                pixel_red   += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j + 1)];
                pixel_green += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j + 1) + 1];
                pixel_blue  += -1 * (short)original[3 * (header.width * i + j + 1) + 2];

                // put it all together now
                if(pixel_red < 0)
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j)]     = 0;
                else if(pixel_red > 255)
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j)]     = 255;
                else
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j)]     = (unsigned char)pixel_red;

                if(pixel_green < 0)
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 1] = 0;
                else if(pixel_green > 255)
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 1] = 255;
                else
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 1] = (unsigned char)pixel_green;

                if(pixel_blue < 0)
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 2] = 0;
                else if(pixel_blue > 255)
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 2] = 255;
                else
                    pixel_array[3 * (header.width * i + j) + 2] = (unsigned char)pixel_blue;
            }
        }
    }

    return pixel_array;
}
```

Please, tell me what's wrong. The whole program should load up a PPM image and "sharpen" it by convolution matrix. The posted piece of code is the sharpening process. Image is in PPM binary RGB format.

Comment: You are corrupting the heap. Check that you are writing to memory that you have allocated.

Comment: Those calculated indices/offsets look worrying.  I suggest that you split up those expressons/statements into 2 - first calculate the index, eg 'index=3 * (header.width * i + j)', then use it: 'short pixel_red   = 5 * (short)original[index]'.  Then, using your debugger and/or printf's, check that all the indices used are as required and in range of the total malloced.

Comment: .. then, when you find out were the index calc is wrong and out-of-bounds, fix it:)

Comment: Possibly the code that corrupts the heap is in here, but I don't think you've posted the code that triggers the abort: the only `free()` I can see is an unnecessary one, if the `malloc()` returned `null`: unnecessary but should be safe. Look in the code that uses the return value from `apply_filter()` and then frees it.

Comment: You can simplify more stuff, eg 'totalMalloced=header.width * header.height * 3;' and 'unsigned char *pixel_array = malloc(totalMalloced);'.  Printf it out.  Then you could maybe add checks: 'if !(index<totalMalloced') indexError();' after each index calculation.  Always think 'how can I easily debug my code', not 'how can I make may code look compact and clever'.

Comment: Easy Allocate 20 bytes - Write 21 bytes - Heap corrupted.

Comment: @AAT I'm calling `exit(int)` function that should exit the program with specified return value immediately, this is where `free()` comes handy, when exiting program by an error. @ThingyWotsit So you recommend me to print out the total malloced size and check the index out of memory occurance?

Comment: How did you mean to print out index out of range? Added code to do it: `if(red_index >= malloced || red_index_row_prev >= malloced || red_index_row_next >= malloced || red_index_col_prev >= malloced || red_index_col_next >= malloced)` and nothing happens. I compiled again, ran, and the same error occured, with no more info dumped. `size_t malloced = header.width * header.height * 3;`, `int red_index          = 3 * (header.width * i + j);` and similar (according to original code).

Comment: All of the `(short)` casts are redundant; look up "integer promotion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your discussion and tips, I forgot to let you know that it was resolved :)

The solution was simple: I just overlooked a typo :D I've corrected the typo (and number of mistakes in further code) and it works like charm :) I forgot to add an `=` character in `less-or-equal` condition (anoted like `<=`), so it incorrectly filled array and created less data array than required.

Thank you for participation in solving the issue, though :)